# Simplest way to add a tooltip to Dojo Tree node?

Tags: tree, dojo, tooltip

I have seen a number of suggestions on how to add a tooltip to Dojo Tree node, and some don't seem to work and others have me asking other questions...

One way I have tried with limited success is this:

```
var myTree = new dijit.Tree({
                model: treeModel,
                id: "myTree",
                showRoot: false,
                persist: false,
                onClick: function(item){                                                
                    console.log(item.name);
                },
                _onNodeMouseEnter : function(node, evt){
                    var tip = new dijit.Tooltip({
                        label: node.item.name,                      
                        connectId: [node.domNode.id]
                    });
                    }                                                       
                });
```

But it has the odd behavior of only creating the tooltip when coming from a node higher up in the tree, and only if you mouse into the expando from the top edge...

A second attempt I looked at the Tree's onMouseEnter method, but it doesn't have access to a node's data item, and so I would have to go through what seems a bit of logic to get the item data by ...looking up the current node id via navigating the DOM tree, then looking for that item in the store?...

Finally I discovered there is a 'getTooltip(item)' method on Tree, but when I set it up:

```
var myTree = new dijit.Tree({
                model: treeModel,
                id: "myTree",
                showRoot: false,
                persist: false,
                onClick: function(item){                                                
                    console.log(item.Obi_Id);
                },
                getTooltip: function(item){
                    return item.Secondary_Names;
                }
            });
```

the tooltip is just a regular HTML 'title' popup...

What is the correct (easy) way to accomplish dojo tooltips on dynamic (lazy) tree nodes?
-robbie

Answer (score 8):

This is the easiest way!

```
var myTree = new dijit.Tree({
    model: treeModel,
    id: "myTree",
    showRoot: false,
    persist: false,
    onClick: function(item){                                                
       console.log(item.name);
    },
    _onNodeMouseEnter: function (node,evt) {
       dijit.showTooltip(node.item.name,node.domNode)
    },
    _onNodeMouseLeave: function (node,evt) {
       dijit.hideTooltip(node.domNode);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use the `getTooltip` attribute:

```
new Tree
({ 
    model: model, 
    getTooltip: function(item) { return "A tooltip!"; }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
define(["dojo/aspect","dijit/Tree","dijit/Tooltip"] ,function(aspect,dijit_Tree,dijit_Tooltip) {
    var tree=new dijit_Tree({....});

    //dijit.showTooltip dijit.hideTooltip defined in Tooltip.js

    //copied from dndContainer.js:
    // aspect.after(this.tree, "_onNodeMouseEnter", lang.hitch(this, "onMouseOver"), true)

    var ttf_on=function(node,evt){dijit.showTooltip("Rev="+node.item.latestRevision,node.domNode)};

    var ttf_off=function(node,evt){dijit.hideTooltip(node.domNode);};

    aspect.after(tree,"_onNodeMouseEnter",ttf_on,true);
    aspect.after(tree,"_onNodeMouseLeave",ttf_off,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not had the pleasure of working with Tree before, but have you tried spawning a new Tooltip using: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tooltip.html

Comment: Yes, my first attempt above uses this technique with the _onNodeMouseEnter event, but there was strange behavior with the mousing only bringing up the tooltip intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the onMouseOver event and bind to that a Dijit Tooltip.

```
    new Tree({ 
        model: model, 
        onMouseOut: function(e){ 
            var node = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(e.target);
            Tooltip.hide(node.labelNode); 
        },
        onMouseOver: function(e) {
            var node = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(e.target);
            Tooltip.show("A tooltip!", node.labelNode);
        }
    });
```